# How to get data from API with GAS

Tags: json, google-apps-script

First, I'm not a non-native, so there're some mistakes.And I'm a newbie.

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.ookami.me/v1/news/public?sport_id=1");

  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var news = JSON.parse(json.getContentText());

  Logger.log("id");
  Logger.log("url");
  Logger.log("image");

}
```

[CODE](https://script.google.com/a/ookamiinc.com/macros/d/1h2D9g87wdDd0h2kBE7otJqnDa0DuYB9xPTlPNBjWyUuiW1hKPxW-OZRb/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvGwRh5BwFLZemN87-Jtwerg7oXquEa_5yona8ovYjx7bI_hH7W-Vq9eaobbr15rH5R0NSrJNHEUNM8upQ7PmL3K_RE5F_SnkfbvFcsEc-udLmcMlqQFldet6T5VlySld9CFEIHcYIc&splash=yes)

I wrote "news" in line8's code, and that time, displayed the log. but wrote again, didn't display.
And the log displayed with id, url, image and so on, so I added the code on line6 and wrote the code on line8 to line10. But a log displayed "undefined".

I want to get data about id, url, image from this [API](https://api.ookami.me/v1/news/public?sport_id=1) with GAS.
And the data, I'll export to spread sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

At this line:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

You have all the data in this format:

[image]

I you want the element news, you need to change your line `var news = JSON.parse(json.getContentText());` to `var news = json.news;`

Then you can loop through all the values:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
    var obj = news[i];
    Logger.log(obj.summary);
  }
```

To export to spreadsheet, you just need to populate an Array inside the loop, and it should look like this:

```
  var rows = []; // new values
  for(var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
    var obj = news[i];
    rows.push([obj.id, obj.image,obj.url]); //your JSON entities here
  }
  Logger.log(rows);
```